# How to do vector addition in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first from scratch game project. I'm trying to make a pinball game but I don't want to just "watch a video on how to make a pinball game". I want to run into the problems and learn how to tackle them as they come.

So far, attaching script to a sprite was issue #1 but I've kinda worked that out. Issue #2 was creating variables and having them translate to real object values. After multiple hours of trial and error I eventually just copied someone elses script that had the most basic setup possible, then broke it and rebuilt it to what I have below with the addition of void Update.

My question is mostly to gather a better understanding but also about a new problem of mine.
Issue #3 is currently when I click play, it moves the object only once. I thought void update is supposed to call every frame?
I would also like to know why when I do transform.position, why can't I do transform.position += (value 1, value 2)? From what I've come up with from experimenting, the only way to alter transform.position is to do = new Vector everytime which I don't fully understand... Another way of wording this part of the question would be: Is there a shorter way of writing a vector transformation or is this the only way the change can be written?

Below is the code. I appreciate any answers even if it's simply directing on the right path to find the information I want.

```
    public float width, height, xSpeed, ySpeed, xPosition, yPosition;
    public Vector2 position, scale;
    
    void Start() {
        // Initialise the variables
        width = 0.5f;
        height = 0.5f;
        xSpeed = 0;
        ySpeed = -1f;
        xPosition = 0;
        yPosition = 3.5f;

        // set the scaling
        Vector2 scale = new Vector2(width, height);
        transform.localScale = scale;
        
        // set the position
        transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition);
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition + xSpeed, 
                                        yPosition + ySpeed);
    }
```

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would recommend you changing the title of the question to something that is a bit more on point, so that people have an idea what programming concept your question is about! :) I would recommend something like "How to do vector addition in Unity".

I will go through your questions one-by-one:

Yes, the Update-Function is called every frame! With each call of `Update()` you set your position to exactly the same value again and again. That is why it is not moving. Neither the xPosition/yPosition nor the xSpeed/ySpeed variables are changing after they have been defined in `Start()`, so your Update Function will always set your position to `(0, 2.5, 0)`.

You can do **Vector addition**! But in order to do that, you need to properly write it in your code, by which I mean **you need to make a vector out of the values you want to add** and only then you can add them to the position vector! So if you wanted to add the xSpeed/ySpeed values ontop of your position, it would look like that:

```
transform.position += new Vector2(xSpeed, ySpeed);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've updated the title as such. :)

Your explanation has helped me understand the problem much better. Thank you!

However I now have a different error. While what you have said makes a ton of sense, Unity seems to think otherwise lol
I now get error: Operator '+=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'

It seems to me that I need to do that calculation within the brackets OR do the calculation before this line of code and have the vector update accordingly 
eg. xPosition += xSpeed
transform.... (xPosition,...)
I'll try it and let you know

Comment: Yep, worked! Although I didn't use your exact line of code, I want you to know that you still solved my problem by helping me understand the problem better which is huge for me! I really apprecaite that. :)

xPosition += xSpeed;
        yPosition += ySpeed;
        transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition);

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jayne, this is what the code ended up turning into, hope this helps anyone else who just wants a straightforward way to alter a vector:

```
public float width, height, xSpeed, ySpeed, xPosition, yPosition;
    public Vector2 position, scale;
    
    void Start() {
        // Initialise the variables
        width = 0.5f;
        height = 0.5f;
        xSpeed = 0;
        ySpeed = -0.01f;
        xPosition = 0;
        yPosition = 3.5f;

        // set the scaling
        Vector2 scale = new Vector2(width, height);
        transform.localScale = scale;
        
        // set the position
        transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition);
    }

    void Update() {
        // Move the pinball
        xPosition += xSpeed;
        yPosition += ySpeed;
        transform.position = new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition);
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my answer helped!

Just one little note - your variables xPosition and yPosition now seem to simply store your transforms position. So what is the reason of keeping them around as variables? You can use `transform.position.x` or `transform.position.y` instead :)

(Just be aware that you can not directly change the x and y values of a vector separately - you either have to do vector addition or assign a whole new vector with the updated values to change them)

Comment: Thanks again for more of your feedback Jayne. :)

I'll keep that in mind, that sounds like an even more refined way of doing what I want :D

You might also enjoy knowing that what I wanted the pinball to do... actually ended up being easier to achieve again by adding a rigid body. I had no idea that rigid body worked the same in unity2d as it does unity3d. But time not wasted, i now know how to use vectors which will be great for when i start working on the paddles!

Comment: Awesome - I'm wishing you best of luck for your project and a great learning experience! :)